# Proof of Burnside's theorem

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, representation-theory

Let $|G| = p^{a}q^{b}$ where $p\neq q$ and $a,b$ are positive integers (i.e. excluding the case where $G$ is a $p$-group).

In preparation for this proof, I have shown that if $Z(G) = 1$ there exists a proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$.

My attempted proof:

Suppose that if $|G| = p^{a'}q^{b'}$ where $a'\leq a$ and $b'\leq b$, not both equal, then $G$ is solvable. We proceed the induction on $|G|$ by considering the two cases $Z(G) = 1$ and $Z(G) \neq 1$.

Assume that $Z(G)=1$, then by the preparatory result we know there exists a proper nontrivial normal subgroup $N$ of $G$. Since $|N|$ divides $|G|$, $|N| < |G|$ and $|G/N| < |G|$ we have by the induction hypothesis that $N$ and $G/N$ are solvable, thus $G$ is also solvable.

Assume that $Z(G) \neq 1$, moreover assume that $Z(G) \neq G$ because then $G$ is abelian and trivially solvable. Then $Z(G)$ is a proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$, and and $G$ is solvable by a similar argument to the one above.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: What's "4a)" in the case $Z(G)=1$?

Comment: @jpvee Oh woops, I meant to edit that out. It's the preparatory result.

Comment: Well, if you can use that preparatory result, then your proof is fine. However, I'd be curious to know how you proved the preparatory result, because that one is really the hard part...

Comment: @jpvee I can post it as an answer, although that too uses a "preparatory result". These are part of an exercise set in which each problem is incorporated in the solution to the next ones.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to my question, but my proof of the preparatory result stated in the beginning of the post.

The setup is the same as in my post.

$\textbf{Lemma}$: If $Z(G)=1$ then there exists a proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$.

Suppose $Z(G) = 1$, and let $C$ be a set of representatives for each conjugacy class of $G$. We have the class equation 
                        \begin{equation}\label{eq:class}
       |G| =\sum_{x\in C}[G:N(x)]
      \end{equation} 
                        where $N(x) = \{a \in G|axa^{-1} = x\}$ and $|C(x)| = [G:N(x)]$. The equation above can be modified by letting $C' \subset C$ be the subset containing representatives for each conjugacy class having more than one element (note that $1\notin C'$), yielding
                        \begin{equation}
       |G| =|Z(G)| + \sum_{x\in C'}[G:N(x)] = 1 + \sum_{x\in C'}[G:N(x)]
      \end{equation}
                        Now, because $|G|=p^{q}q^{b}$ we have that $q$ divides $\big(1 + \sum_{x\in C'}[G:N(x)]\big)$. Clearly, $q$ cannot divide $[G:N(x)]$ for all $x\in C'$ because then it would divide $1$ as well. Therefore there exists an $x\in G\backslash \{1\}$ such that $q$ does not divide $$|C(x)| = [G:N(x)] = \frac{p^{a}q^{b}}{|N(x)|}$$ which implies that $|C(x)|=p^{k}$ for $k\leq a$. $\textbf{From a previous problem:}$ We know that there exists a nontrivial irreducible representation $\rho :G \rightarrow GL(V)$ whose kernel $N \triangleleft G$ is a proper normal subgroup. Moreover, the image of $x$ in $G/N$, i.e. $xN$, lies in $Z(G/N)$. Suppose that $N$ is the trivial subgroup, then $x \in Z(G) = 1$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $N$ is a proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$.

EDIT: The statement of the previous problem:

Let $g\in G\backslash\{1\}$ and suppose $|\mathcal{C}(g)|$ is a $p$-power for some prime $p$.

(a) Show that there exists a nontrivial irreducible representation $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(V)$ with character $\chi$ such that $\chi(g) \neq 0$ and $p$ does not divide $\chi(1)$.

(b) Let $\rho$ be as in (a) and explain why $\rho_{g}$ is multiplication by a complex number.

(c) Let $N \leq G$ be the kernel of $\rho$. Verify that $N \neq G$ and that the image of $g$ in $G/N$ lies in the center of $G/N$.

Comment: I don't see the point of any of the words between "Suppose $Z(G)=1$ and **From a previous problem:**, unless that previous problem requires some knowledge about centralizers. If it does, you should spell that out in your proof. None of us here have access to your "previous problems".

Comment: Also, similar to the complaint in the comment to your post, the hard part of the proof is again pushed into background results.

Comment: Yes, and as I explained these are linked problems. I didn't want to post them all because I'm quite confident that they are correct, and these last were the hard ones.

Comment: As I said, your post is not sensible unless you explain how the condition on $|C(x)|$ relates to the existence of $\rho$.

Comment: @DavidHill Ok I suppose you're right. But i'm not going to post the entire problem set with my attempted solutions, so I'll just stick with what I have.

Comment: I recommend you at least provide the statement of the previous exercise.

Comment: @DavidHill Now it's edited in my answer.